# Wrong Charset Encoding with Play Framework 2.1

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a web service that receives a parameter in ISO-8859-1 encoding.

But when I try to read it from the request, I get this characters:

�����

I've tryied all these approaches, but none of the convert the given string to the expected one (áéíóú):

```
    val a = new String(_html.getBytes());
    val b = new String(_html.getBytes(), "UTF-8")
    val c = new String(_html.getBytes(), "ISO-8859-1")
    val d = new String(_html.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8")
    val e = new String(_html.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "ISO-8859-1")
    val f = new String(_html.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8")
    val g = new String(_html.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1")
```

Here is my action:

```
  val inboundMessageForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "html" -> text)(InboundMessage.apply)(InboundMessage.unapply))

  def forward = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
    val inboundMessage = inboundMessageForm.bindFromRequest.get

        // inboundMessage.html =>  �����
   }
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: The inboundmessage library or whatever has decoded it as UTF-8 before handing it to you. This is lossy so you can't do anything at that point - you need to instruct it to decode in ISO-8859-1 or encode the request in UTF-8. I recommend encoding as UTF-8, it's 2013 after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to this question:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/R0ayxNuzR74

Answer (score -1):

If you are running windows, the default encoding (at least in the states, not sure about the rest of the world) is actually "windows-1252", not "ISO-8859-1". You could also try "UTF-16" in case those characters aren't included in the "UTF-8" encoding (which most things other than windows use).