# Play framework 2.2.0 bad character encoding layout

Tags: java, playframework

Play Framework 2.2.0 seems to incorrectly display html content that comes from an Html object inside a layout. Given the following templates:

main.scala.html:

```
@(title : String)(content: Html)
Price 10€
@content
```

index.scala.html:

```
@main("Index") {
    Price: 20€
}
```

The result of rendering index.scala.html is:

```
Price 10€
Price 20�
```

Something happens to the content displayed inside the layout, but not to the content on the outside. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Eclipse was setting different encodings for different files and it was breaking the characters.

A similar post about this problem is here:
[Wrong Charset Encoding with Play Framework 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044263/wrong-charset-encoding-with-play-framework-2-1)